# Find longest and shortest strings in stdin

Tags: bash, shell

This program is intended to read a file from stdin and return the longest and shortest lines. Right now it's in an infinite loop.Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Update: So after reading more about what read does, it's actually right (yay me) but I want to set the delimiter to a newline character while currently the read command is taking a string at every whitespace character. Does anyone know what I can do?

```
read T
short=""
long=""
for i in $T; do
   if [[ $short = "" ]]; then
       short=$i
   elif [[ ${#i} -lt ${#short} ]]; then
      short=$i
   elif [[ ${#i} -gt ${#long} ]];then
      long=$i
   fi
done
echo $short
echo $long
```

Comment: Why do you think this is an infinite loop? Also this doesn't operate on lines. It operates on words because the value of `$T` is being word-split. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for help on reading line-by-line correctly.

Comment: Because I don't know what I'm doing haha I have to set the delimiter to a newline though.

Comment: And all of these look a little...advanced for my course's criteria thus far

Comment: `read` does read by lines. Your words are being split when you use `$T` without quoting it. Try `"$T"` instead. Also this script doesn't loop anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't possibly reach an infinite loop, since you are looping over a
necessarily finite variable (`$T`).

I'm going to assume that your script is "hanging" and assume
one of the possible reasons (to provide you one possible
solution to your classroom problem): that the script is sleeping
waiting for data from stdin and no data is being sent to him.

Here's what you could do:

```bash
read short
long=$short
while read line; do
    if [[ ${#line} -lt ${#short} ]]; then
        short=$line
    fi
    if [[ ${#line} -gt ${#long} ]]; then
        long=$line
    fi
done
echo $short
echo $long
```

Notice that I've first initialized the `short` and `long` with the
first line of input, or empty string on stdin's EOF.  Then I attempt
to read more lines in a while loop to then check for conditions to update `short` and
`long`; it is important to not exclude the line size checks if one
of them applies (like you didn't in your script using `elif`s).

Comment: Looking back at this I'd have to assume it was infinite because stdin reads from keyboard input when stdin is null.